# Collate while parsing xml

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2, collation

On same server I have few databases with diferent collation.
I'm parsing xml as

```
CREATE TABLE #tblDocuments
(
    Document varchar(5) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
   ,DocCode varchar(15) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
   ,Ammount decimal(18,2)
   );

IF @@ERROR <> 0
    GOTO ErrorHandl;

INSERT INTO #tblDocuments
(
    Document
   ,DocCode
   ,Ammount
)

SELECT 
    Tbl.Col.value('@DocType','varchar(3)') AS Document
   ,Tbl.Col.value('@DocCode','varchar(15)') AS DocCode
   ,Tbl.Col.value('@Ammount','decimal(18,2)') AS Ammount
FROM 
    @xmlData.nodes('/Documents/document') AS Tbl(Col);
```

Is there a way to parse xml without first creating table with predefined collation. Something like (I know this code isn't working)

```
SELECT 
    Tbl.Col.value('@DocType','varchar(3) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT') AS Document
   ,Tbl.Col.value('@DocCode','varchar(15) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT') AS DocCode
   ,Tbl.Col.value('@Ammount','decimal(18,2) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT') AS Ammount
INTO #tblDocuments
FROM 
    @xmlData.nodes('/Documents/document') AS Tbl(Col);enter code here
```

Thx in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the `COLLATE` outside of the `.value()` function:

```
SELECT 
    Tbl.Col.value('@DocType','varchar(3)') COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT AS [Document]
   ,Tbl.Col.value('@DocCode','varchar(15)') COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT AS [DocCode]
   ,Tbl.Col.value('@Ammount','decimal(18,2)') AS Ammount
INTO #tblDocuments
FROM 
    @xmlData.nodes('/Documents/document') AS Tbl(Col);
    enter code here
```

Also, you don't use `COLLATE` on anything but string datatypes (`CHAR` / `VARCHAR` / `NCHAR` / `NVARCHAR` -- and even the deprecated `TEXT` and `NTEXT` datatypes).